# Change style programmatically

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm attempting to follow the [Custom property API for Polymer elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-api) docs with regards to updating an element's CSS properties (and styles) programmatically but can't seem to get it working.  Here is my current attempt:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/master/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-namecard">
  <style>
    :host {
      --color: green;
    }

    span {
      color: var(--color, orange);
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <div>
      Hi! My name is <span>{{name}}</span>
    </div>
    <button on-click="redClick">Set text to Red</button>
    <button on-click="blueClick">Set text to Blue</button>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-namecard',
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: String
        }
      },
      redClick: function() {
        console.log('Setting "--color" red');
        this.customStyle['--color'] = 'red';
        this.updateStyles();
      },
      blueClick: function() {
        console.log('Setting "--color" blue');
        this.customStyle['--color'] = 'blue';
        this.updateStyles();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<my-namecard name="Sean"></my-namecard>
```

I've also attempted not setting a CSS property and using a direct style such as:

```
redClick: function() {
    console.log('Setting "color" red');
    this.customStyle['color'] = 'red';
    this.updateStyles();
}
```

I've created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/techniq/pen/jPLmEL?editors=100) demonstrating the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've hit a bug in the current version of Polymer, where a style change like this will propagate to child Polymer elements, but not to the element itself. See:

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1851

The workaround is to call `Polymer.updateStyles()` instead of `this.updateStyles()`.

Here's the updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdyJPY).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use customStyle[...] without a custom  CSS property?

Comment: If you want to set a standard style property (not a custom property), is what you want the standard `style` property? (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)